# How to change url of identifier with src of image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover, getelementbyid

I want to hover the cursor over image and bring it up on as another div's background image. I am doing the following in js:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage="url(previewPic.src)";
}
```

The src contains an online link so no worries. I want to access div by id "image" and replace it's bg image's url to src of image i hover on. I made a function call that sents me object of current image hovered on.

Here is the full code:

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage="url(previewPic.src)";
}
```

```css
#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Comment: You're close, you just need to use interpolation: ``document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage=`url(${previewPic.src})`;`` , or concatenate the strings `document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage="url(" + previewPic.src + ")";`

Comment: Do what the Heretic said, it solves

Comment: @AksJacoves Next time, just click the up arrow next to the comment to show your support.

Comment: Thank you so much! @HereticMonkey . I spent my whole day searching for this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to apply something like the following CSS:

```css
background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg");
```

But you're actually doing this:

```css
background-image: url(previewPic.src);
```

This is the javascript line you need to update, with corrected string concatenation:

```js
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage= "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
```

Code snippet:

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage= "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
}
```

```css
#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg')" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG')" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg')" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Run_Script it was really helpful!